# dividend token with doge coin reward system

Tags: solidity, reward

i have a token that reward eth to token holders but i want to use another coin( doge/cardano) for reward. i am not able to do it. any help would be great.

here is the code

```
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
    // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // make the swap
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}

function swapAndSendDividends(uint256 tokens) private {
    swapTokensForEth(tokens);
    uint256 dividends = address(this).balance;

    (bool success,) = address(dividendTracker).call{value: dividends}("");
    if (success) {
        emit SentDividends(tokens, dividends);
    }
}

}
```

full code in git hub:  https://github.com/coderbang1/eth-distri-token/blob/main/code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this and notice the path[2]

```
 // generate the pancakeswap pair path of weth -> dividend
    address[] memory path = new address[](3);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = pancakeswapV2Router.WETH();
    path[2] = _dividendRewardToken;

    _approve(address(this), address(pancakeswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // make the swap
    pancakeswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      tokenAmount,
      0, // accept any amount of tokens
      path,
      recipient,
      block.timestamp
    );
```

Comment: notice path 2 ?

Comment: Here dividendRewardToken is the contract address of the token you want to give reward for your holders
`path[2] = _dividendRewardToken;`

Comment: but it gives me error when i add it

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: not identifies declared